# How do you use the user keyword "list"?

Tags: c, keyword

For a practical work I am working on I have to use a "preset" structure for certain functions. One of them was as follows:

```
int initEmployees(Employee* list, int len)
{

//From here is my code

    int isError = -1;
    if ( len > 0)
    {
        len--;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        {

//This line is the problem, I know is not right but not sure how to fix it
            list[i].isEmpty = 1;

/*My other guesses where:
*(list + i).isEmpty = 1;
(*Employee + i).isEmpty = 1;
but im quiet sure they won't work either*/

        }
        isError=0;
    }
    return isError;
}
```

Tried googling it: "Is codeblocks user keyword releted to STL!" and going through a 1991 C book (Spanish edit) checking if it contined references to any library containing it but nothing.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but there is no `list` keyword in C.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also this question lacks debugging info (expected behaviour, a minimal reproducible example <that will compile>, actual behaviour, etc.) Also this has nothing to do with [codeblocks]...

Comment: Noted, thanks for the tips. I'll have them in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, `list` in this context is a variable name, not a keyword.

And there's nothing wrong with that loop code, provided that the `Employee` structure actually *has* an `isEmpty` member that you can assign `1` to.

It simply runs through a provided array (called `list`), setting each element in turn to be empty.

However, your manipulation of `len` seems a bit off, I suspect it won't modify the last element in the list since you decrement it before running the loop.

I suspect a more canonical version (including that fix) would be something like:

```
int initEmployees(Employee* list, int len) {
    // Error if no elements in list.

    if (len < 1) return -1;

    // Mark each entry as empty.

    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        list[i].isEmpty = 1;
    }

    // Everything is okay.

    return 0;
}
```

But I'd also question raising an error on a list size of zero. It seems to me that it's perfectly okay to modify all elements of an empty list - that just involves doing nothing.

And, if you use unsigned values for sizes of things (e.g., `size_t`), your "negative" problem goes away.

Comment: (Trys hardcoding it)
*Damn he's right* I am an idiot been 3 hours knoking my head over this
about {len} you'r right too

Comment: Yeah, teach says I can not use more than one return per function. something about it beeng readable. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: @PlainSight: that's the difference between academia and reality :-) Although, to be fair to your educator, multiple return points *can* become an issue for complex code, so they're probably correct at steering you away from that during initial education. As you become more adept, you'll discover that this rule is *not* so correct all the time (such as using `return` early in a function for "fail fast" scenarios).  You can just reintroduce the `isError` stuff to adapt my code to the "one exit point" strategy.

Answer (score 0):

`list` isn't a keyword in C.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword

Comment: In codeblocks it's shown in italic green which is used for User Keywords (usualy referenced in some library like "end" and "beguin" in STL C++)

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  It isn't a C keyword.

Comment: @PlainSight: it's possible the colouring may be set up for C++ rather than C. In the former, `list` is a standard collection class so that would make sense. *User* keywords in CodeBlocks are special syntax items but they are not *reserved* keywords like `for` or `int`, so I think this may just a misunderstanding in terms.